# Extjs get Model by Controller

Tags: extjs

I get controller bind to model, and model with proxy on it. I try to get model in controller init function. I use next code:

```
Ext.define("AM.controller.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
            'Grid'
        ],
  models:[          
          'AM.model.Points'
          ],
    init: function(){
    var m = this.getModel('AM.model.Points');
    m.getCount();
}
```

But the getCount is not defined. When I print variable m it says it is function: constructor() :

```
function constructor() {


            return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments) || null;
        }
```

What should I do to get right model object of controller?

Here I add my store, my model with proxy on it:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.ServerStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',   
        model: 'AM.model.Points'
     });

Ext.define('AM.model.Points', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        idProperty: {
              name: 'UUID', 
              type: String,
              isUnique: true
            },  
        fields: [ 
                  {
                    name: 'NO',
                    type: "string"
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Y',
                    type: "int"
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'ROW',
                    type: 'int'
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'SEAT',
                    type: 'string'
                  },

                  {
                    name: 'PROCEEDED',
                    type: 'int'
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'X',
                    type: "int"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "CurrentPlace",
                    type: "int",  
                    defaultValue: 0  
                  }
                  ],

                  proxy: {
                      type: 'ajax',            
                      url: 'http://localhost:81/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/EnterpriseOrg-MainChannel-Site/ru_RU/-/RUR/HallScheme-PrepareHSXML?HallSchemeElementUUID=zm1VFZxy014AAAENz2ZCr4MF',
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                      params: {
                            "HallSchemeElementUUID" : "zm1VFZxy014AAAENz2ZCr4MF"
                        },                      
                        remoteSort: true,
                      reader: {
                          type: 'xml',
                          record: 'PLACE'
                      }, 

                    writer: {
                        type: 'xml',                  
                        root: 'PLACE'
                    }
                }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Models are used to defined a record structure in a store. The getCount() does not exist for the Model class in ExtJS.

Instead, you need to be referencing your store in your controller that contains your models and call getCount() on the store instance.

E.g.

```
var store = this.getStore('storeName');
//or
//var store = Ext.getStore('storeID');
var numRecords = store.getCount();
```

Comment: Im not able to get  model by any means. I need it to update store records. I tried to get model by store, no success. Thats why I tried to get it by controller. Can u share working code for store record updaing? Thanx in advance.

Comment: What you have linked to is to do with databound components and that doc even tells you NOT to use that class directly. If you want to update store records then you need code to retrieve the records in the first place. You have passed in 'Grid' to your views config, so why not use this.getView('Grid').getStore() and then you can get to the particular records you are interested in for updating, e.g. byID or some other way.

Comment: I tried so. The code doesnt work for me   stringStore.each(function(record,idx){
          val = record.get('UUID');           
            record.set('UUID', uuid);           
         record.commit();
   });

Comment: So I read on to doc and got out that I need model object to update records. Can u share some code plz?

Comment: The record parameter passed into the store.each() function on your store is an instance of your model. You may also actually need to call record.beginEdit(), then do your record.set(...) and then end with record.endEdit()

Comment: Seems no effect for me for some mistic reason   serverStore.each(function(rec) {
            rec.beginEdit();
               rec.set('SEAT', '10000000');
            rec.endEdit();
            rec.commit();
           });
           serverStore.commitChanges();
           serverStore.reload();
           console.log(serverStore);

Comment: Ya was my mistake - store wasnt yet loaded.

Comment: So is your issue sorted now?

Comment: )) Now Im stuck at proxy writer. When trying to sync(). He writes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  in extjs module Writer.js :  // Make sure that if a mapping is in place the mapped id name is used instead of the default field name. 
            mappedIdProperty = fields.get(record.idProperty)[this.nameProperty] || record.idProperty;

Comment: Please add your store and model config code to your original question

Comment: XML looks like this:   <ROOT>
<PLACE>
<NO>3-ий Амфитеатр</NO>
<X>584</X>
<Y>350</Y>
<ROW>1</ROW>
<SEAT>1</SEAT>
<PROCEEDED>0</PROCEEDED>
<UUID>9mxVFZxyrqIAAAEfhqZ4tkDH</UUID>
</PLACE>..